# Scheme - using foldr inside map and making the foldr proc use the current element given from the map iteration

Tags: dictionary, scheme, closures, racket, fold

I'm trying to write the following function which gets 2 lists of lists and returns the cartesian product of those lists.

here's what I wrote:

```
;; Signature: mix-rows(rows1 rows2)
;; Purpose: returns a list of rows of the cartesian product of both rows 
;; Type: [ List(Row) * List(Row) -> List(Row) ]
;; Tests:
;; (mix-rows (list '(10 11) '(20 21)) (list '('u 'v) '('p 'q)))
;; ==> ((10 11 'u 'v)
;;      (10 11 'p 'q)
;;      (20 21 'u 'v)
;;      (20 21 'p 'q))
(define mix-rows
  (lambda (rows1 rows2)
    (map (lambda (row1)
           (foldr (lambda (row2)
                  (append row1 row2))
                  '()
                rows2))
         rows1)))
```

for some reason the last lambda won't recognize row1 which was given from the function map iterating through rows1.

I want the last lambda to iterate through rows2 and append each element to row1 and after all rows2 elements were appended row1 will change to the next element in rows1.

why wan't the lambda recognize row1?

thanks.

Comment: you probably don't intended to double quote `uvpq`, just use `'(u v)` and `'(p q)` which are sugared versions of `(list (quote u) (quote v))` and `(list (quote p) (quote q))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if all you want is a `cartesian-product` function, you can use [`cartesian-product`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29) from `racket/list`.

```
> (cartesian-product
   (list '(10 11) '(20 21))
   (list '('u 'v) '('p 'q)))
'(((10 11) ('u 'v)) ((10 11) ('p 'q)) ((20 21) ('u 'v)) ((20 21) ('p 'q)))
```

Your test case is slightly different from this, because your test case splices the inner lists and this doesn't. But, if that's what you need you can easily fix it with `(map append* ...)`. The [`append*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldr#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append*%29%29) function flattens a list of lists one level down.

```
> (define (mix-rows rows1 rows2)
    (map append* (cartesian-product rows1 rows2)))
> (mix-rows
   (list '(10 11) '(20 21))
   (list '('u 'v) '('p 'q)))
'((10 11 'u 'v) (10 11 'p 'q) (20 21 'u 'v) (20 21 'p 'q))
```

Although if you want to design it from scratch, the problem with your implementation is that `foldr` expects a function `(X Y -> Y)`, a two-argument function, but you gave it a function `(Row -> Row)`, a one argument function. You could fix that, but from what I can see, you don't really need a `foldr` at all there. You probably meant a `map` there too.

```
(define mix-rows
  (lambda (rows1 rows2)
    (map (lambda (row1)
           (map (lambda (row2)
                  (append row1 row2))
                rows2))
         rows1)))
```

Although, this still fails your test case, producing

```
> (mix-rows
   (list '(10 11) '(20 21))
   (list '('u 'v) '('p 'q)))
'(((10 11 'u 'v) (10 11 'p 'q)) ((20 21 'u 'v) (20 21 'p 'q)))
```

To get rid of that extra layer of nested lists, you can use [`append*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldr#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append*%29%29) to flatten that list of lists one level down.

```
;; Signature: mix-rows(rows1 rows2)
;; Purpose: returns a list of rows of the cartesian product of both rows 
;; Type: [ List(Row) * List(Row) -> List(Row) ]
;; Tests:
;; (mix-rows (list '(10 11) '(20 21)) (list '('u 'v) '('p 'q)))
;; ==> ((10 11 'u 'v)
;;      (10 11 'p 'q)
;;      (20 21 'u 'v)
;;      (20 21 'p 'q))
(define mix-rows
  (lambda (rows1 rows2)
    (append*
     (map (lambda (row1)
            (map (lambda (row2)
                   (append row1 row2))
                 rows2))
          rows1))))
```

However, if you want a real Cartesian product, without splicing the rows, you can fix it by changing `(append row1 row2)` to `(list row1 row2)`.

```
(define mix-rows
  (lambda (rows1 rows2)
    (append*
     (map (lambda (row1)
            (map (lambda (row2)
                   (list row1 row2))
                 rows2))
          rows1))))
```

Then it matches what [`cartesian-product`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._cartesian-product%29%29) does.